# Blazor sub-page onclick method not found (not defined)

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I have nested Blazor components: MainLayout (modified from the sample project) > Expeditions > EditExpedition > UpdateExpVessels as shown below.

The problem is I'm using an onclick in UpdateExpVessels to call a local method but due to the nesting (I'm assuming) it's not found.  The error message is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: FlipEdit is not defined
> at onclick (localhost꞉7281/editExpedition/1000:1:1)

Is there something special I need to do to call a method on the same Blazor page in a nested structure?

**In MainLayout:**

```html
<div class="top-row px-4 small-font">
    <Expeditions />
```

**In Expeditions:**

```
string path = "/editExpedition/" + expedition.ExpeditionID;
<DropdownItem To="@path" 
  Type="ButtonType.Link">@expedition.Name</DropdownItem>
```

**In EditExpedition:**

```html
<td width="25%"><UpdateExpVessels ID="@ID" /></td>
```

**In UpdateExpVessels:**

```
<Icon Name=IconName.Pencil Color=IconColor.Success onclick="FlipEdit"/>


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int? ID { get; set; }

    private bool editPage = true;

    public void FlipEdit()
    {
        editPage = !editPage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Blazor handles Clicks and other events a little differently
You are trying to bind event the traditional HTML way

```
<Icon Name=IconName.Pencil Color=IconColor.Success onclick="FlipEdit"/>
```

Blazor does not know how to find and execute hte method on a component class instead use

```
<Icon Name=IconName.Pencil Color=IconColor.Success @onclick="FlipEdit"/>
```

This should find the method and im not sure if Icon accepts callbacks so I would wrap it around in a button:

```
<button @onclick="FlipEdit">
    <Icon Name=IconName.Pencil Color=IconColor.Success />
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I changed it to a button as you suggested but still doesn't work... I don't get the error anymore, but doesn't appear the method is called.  I placed a line in the method to write to the debug window but the messages isn't written.  Is there a dependency or something I need to add for this to work?  I have '@attribute [StreamRendering]' set.

Comment: @Josh Try executing it locally and using breakpoints, it is often better than trying to find a one line log, especially if you are not sure where the log is being output.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing ;).  I have a breakpoint on the first line in my method but it's never getting caught.  I have breakpoints set elsewhere in @code that catch when the page loads but the method breakpoint doesn't.

Comment: Net8?  RenderMode?  Where is interactivity set?  Do you have an Interactive or statically configured component?

Comment: yes Net8.  Thank you!  I had to set the @rendermode to InteractiveServer 